# How do I display different content with a jsp:include and jsp:param

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have two versions of a component to be displayed based on the url string for example:

```
http://localhost/index.li?id=a
```

This is supposed to display version 1

```
http://localhost/index.li?id=b
```

This is supposed to display version 2

What I was told to do is the following in the parent jsp file:

```
<jsp:include page="/somepage/components/acomponent.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="param1" value="value1"/>
        <jsp:param name="param2" value="value2"/>
</jsp:include>
```

The question I have is in my acomponent.jsp what name and values do I use to switch between versions? For example:

```
<div id="version1"></div>

<div id="version2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the id off of the URI (either with JSTL or Scriptlets) and then pass that into your acomponent.jsp file like so.

```
<jsp:include page= "/somepage/components/acomponent.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="value1" value="<id you got off of the URI>"
</jsp:include>
```

Then, within your acomponent.jsp file, you could do something like this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${value1 eq 'a'}">
        --JSP CODE FOR WHEN A NEEDS TO BE USED
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        --JSP CODE FOR WHEN B NEEDS TO BE USED
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use <c:choose>? It has to be only jsp:include and jsp:param?

Comment: It is nested within a <c:choose> tag. Remember this is just one component that has two versions. So there are more <jsp:include> and <jsp:param> in this file. I just want to know how I determine the name and the value of the param so that when a certain url string is used the correct version is shown.